# Open and connected in $R^n$ revised

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, connectedness

I am trying to understand the following: If we have an open and connected set in $R^n$ then it can be connected with line segments parallel to the axes.

I managed to prove this:
 If a set $U$ is open and connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then we can prove it is polygonally connected(there is a path formed from line segments completely contained in $U$).

My question now is how would I modify the path such that the line segments remain in $U$ and they are now parallel to the axes?

I would very much appreciate some help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that for any cube $C=[-r,r]^n\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ any point $c=(c_0, c_1,\ldots c_{n-1})\in C$ is polygonally connected to the center of $C$ along the axes.
$$(0,0,0,\ldots,0)\to(c_0,0,0, \ldots, 0)\to(c_0,c_1,0,\ldots0)\to\ldots\to(c_0,c_1,\ldots c_{n-1})$$

Let $G$ be any nonempty open connected set in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $a\in G$.

Now set $A=\{g\in G\mid\text{$g$ is polygonally connected to $a$ along the axes}\}$.

Note that for any any $b\in A$ there's a cube $C=b+[-r,r]^n\subseteq G$ because G is open, so $C\subseteq A$. This means $A$ is open.

And for any $b\in\overline A$ there is a cube $C=b+[-r,r]^n\subseteq G$, so there's also a point $c\in A\cap C$, so $b\in A$. This means $A$ is closed.

Therefore $A=G$, because it's a nonempty clopen subset of a connected set $G$.

Comment: So it suffices to prove that the origin is connected to any point via parallel line segments. But I am not sure how to formally construct these in such a way that it is clear we stay in the set because intuitively, yes, we just start from the origin and move along a direction of a certain axes until we 'hit' the end of U and then move to another direction and so on . This has 2 bugs: $U$ is open so I should restrict myself to a compact subset of $U$ but then what to do to the remaining points of $U$ and secondly how can I make sure I actually arrive at the right location?

Comment: @Whats My Name I don't understand you at all, so I'll just provide a full proof in my answer.

Comment: @Whats My Name: Done. You don't need to construct almost anything, it constructs itself automatically. Also I see you have many questions, but you didn't accept a single answer, you know there's a little checkbox under the arrows used to rate the question, right??

Comment: I will take care of that part. About the problem: now I see that the solution is naturally coming from my initial solution as well, I was missing out on some details. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity we can take the case of $R^2$. We want to go from (a,b) to (c,d) parallel to coordinate axes, but not get out of the given set. We move from (a,b) to (a,c) and test if the path (a,b)-(a,c) is in the set. If yes, we than move from (a,c) to (b,c) and test if (a,c)-(b-c) is in the set. If yes, we are done. But if (a,b)-(a,c) is not in the set, then we go from (a,b) to (a,c/2) and do the same test... We do the same thing for y-axis parallel lines.